# Implementing a ListBox of CheckBoxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Apologies in advance as i'm aware this question has appeared several times. However, i'm struggling to identify where i'm going wrong with my own code. Just looking for a list of checkboxes and names next to them. Currently it compiles ok but the ListBox is empty.

All of the code is within a control called ucDatabases.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="5 5 0 0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**C# Code:**

```
  public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDatabase> Databases;

public class CheckBoxDatabase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private string name;
            private bool isChecked;
            public Database Database;

            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    isChecked = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                }
            }

            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set
                {
                    name = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string strPropertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(strPropertyName));
            }
        }
```

**Helper method to populate some test data:**

```
private void SetTestData()
    {
        const string dbAlias = "Database ";
        Databases = new ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDatabase>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            var db = new Database(string.Format(dbAlias + "{0}", i));
            var newCBDB = new CheckBoxDatabase {Database = db, IsChecked = false, Name = db.Name};

            Databases.Add(newCBDB);
        }
    }
```

Advice and a solution would be much appreciated!

Comment: where do you instantiante your views? where is the DataContext assigned? do you have any binding errors in the Visual Studio output window?

Comment: Where is the field 'Databases'? Is it in a separate class or in the Window class?

Comment: DataContext is currently set to 'this'. No binding errors in output window and i'm not sure what you mean by instantiating views..sorry. Databases is a class level variable in ucDatabases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDatabase> Databases;` is a field.

You should replace it with a Property:

`public ObservableCollection<CheckBoxDatabase> Databases {get;set;};`

Don't forget `INotifyPropertyChanged`!

Comment: "you your replace it with a property" is "you SHOULD replace it" ahah. My mistake. That's what happens when you alt-tab between SO and Warcraft 3 while playing DotA haah.